# GoogleMaps freehand polygon creation worked before, not now

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a page to search customers by a Google map with freehand area selection 1 years ago. I used GDouglasPeucker to do this and when I created the page, everythings work well, but now is not working and I don't understand why!

this is the GDouglasPeucker function:

```
function GDouglasPeucker(source, kink)
/* source[] Input coordinates in GLatLngs   */
/* kink in metres, kinks above this depth kept  */
/* kink depth is the height of the triangle abc where a-b and b-c are two consecutive line segments */ {
var n_source, n_stack, n_dest, start, end, i, sig;
var dev_sqr, max_dev_sqr, band_sqr;
var x12, y12, d12, x13, y13, d13, x23, y23, d23;
var F = ((Math.PI / 180.0) * 0.5);
var index = new Array(); /* aray of indexes of source points to include in the reduced line */
var sig_start = new Array(); /* indices of start & end of working section */
var sig_end = new Array();

/* check for simple cases */

if (source.length < 3)
    return (source);    /* one or two points */

/* more complex case. initialize stack */

n_source = source.length;
band_sqr = kink * 360.0 / (2.0 * Math.PI * 6378137.0);  /* Now in degrees */
band_sqr *= band_sqr;
n_dest = 0;
sig_start[0] = 0;
sig_end[0] = n_source - 1;
n_stack = 1;

/* while the stack is not empty  ... */
while (n_stack > 0) {

    /* ... pop the top-most entries off the stacks */

    start = sig_start[n_stack - 1];
    end = sig_end[n_stack - 1];
    n_stack--;

    if ((end - start) > 1) {  /* any intermediate points ? */

        /* ... yes, so find most deviant intermediate point to
               either side of line joining start & end points */

        x12 = (source[end].lng() - source[start].lng());
        y12 = (source[end].lat() - source[start].lat());
        if (Math.abs(x12) > 180.0)
            x12 = 360.0 - Math.abs(x12);
        x12 *= Math.cos(F * (source[end].lat() + source[start].lat()));/* use avg lat to reduce lng */
        d12 = (x12 * x12) + (y12 * y12);

        for (i = start + 1, sig = start, max_dev_sqr = -1.0; i < end; i++) {

            x13 = (source[i].lng() - source[start].lng());
            y13 = (source[i].lat() - source[start].lat());
            if (Math.abs(x13) > 180.0)
                x13 = 360.0 - Math.abs(x13);
            x13 *= Math.cos(F * (source[i].lat() + source[start].lat()));
            d13 = (x13 * x13) + (y13 * y13);

            x23 = (source[i].lng() - source[end].lng());
            y23 = (source[i].lat() - source[end].lat());
            if (Math.abs(x23) > 180.0)
                x23 = 360.0 - Math.abs(x23);
            x23 *= Math.cos(F * (source[i].lat() + source[end].lat()));
            d23 = (x23 * x23) + (y23 * y23);

            if (d13 >= (d12 + d23))
                dev_sqr = d23;
            else if (d23 >= (d12 + d13))
                dev_sqr = d13;
            else
                dev_sqr = (x13 * y12 - y13 * x12) * (x13 * y12 - y13 * x12) / d12;// solve triangle

            if (dev_sqr > max_dev_sqr) {
                sig = i;
                max_dev_sqr = dev_sqr;
            }
        }

        if (max_dev_sqr < band_sqr) {   /* is there a sig. intermediate point ? */
            /* ... no, so transfer current start point */
            index[n_dest] = start;
            n_dest++;
        }
        else {
            /* ... yes, so push two sub-sections on stack for further processing */
            n_stack++;
            sig_start[n_stack - 1] = sig;
            sig_end[n_stack - 1] = end;
            n_stack++;
            sig_start[n_stack - 1] = start;
            sig_end[n_stack - 1] = sig;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* ... no intermediate points, so transfer current start point */
        index[n_dest] = start;
        n_dest++;
    }
}

/* transfer last point */
index[n_dest] = n_source - 1;
n_dest++;

/* make return array */
var r = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < n_dest; i++)
    r.push(source[index[i]]);
return r;

}
```

and this the function that before works:

```
function drawFreeHand() {

        //the polygon
        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, clickable: false });

        //move-listener
        var move = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (e) {
            poly.getPath().push(e.latLng);
        });

        //mouseup-listener

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'mouseup', function (e) {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(move);
            var path = poly.getPath();
            poly.setMap(null);


            var theArrayofLatLng = path.j;

            console.log(path.j);
            var ArrayforPolygontoUse = GDouglasPeucker(theArrayofLatLng, 50);
            console.log("ArrayforPolygontoUse", ArrayforPolygontoUse);

            if (poly && poly.getPaths) {
                multi_poly = poly.getPaths();
                multi_poly_path.push(ArrayforPolygontoUse);
            } else {
                multi_poly = ArrayforPolygontoUse;
            }

            var polyOptions = {
                map: map,
                //fillColor: '#0099FF',
                fillOpacity: 0.45,
                //strokeColor: '#AA2143',
                strokeWeight: 0,
                clickable: false,
                zIndex: 1,
                path: multi_poly,
                editable: false
            }

            poly = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);

            setSelection(poly);
            google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'mousedown');
            SetNavigaMode();
            enable();

            VisualizzaControlliCustom(false);
        });
    }
```

the line who generates the error is
`poly = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);`

and this is the error!

[image]

somebody can help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var theArrayofLatLng = path.j;
```

Here `j` is minimized field name. It is undocumented and should never be used. Most probably, Google released new version of their API, and this field now has different name, and it will change again in future.

You should use 
`var theArrayofLatLng = path.getArray();` instead